# Form fieldset border not displaying in Tailwind [ Snippet Attached ]

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, fieldset

I am making a simple react app with [**Tailwind css**](https://tailwindcss.com/) .

**Case 1**: Working scenario **without** tailwind:

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-agnesi-y70ue

Here in this example the tailwind is not included and its a simple react app where the fieldset and legend displayed in correct manner along with border surrounded.

**Case 2:** Not working scenario **with** tailwind:

As like the first scenario, I would like to achieve the same kind of UI using Tailwind CSS.

And the thing I have tried is given below,

https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-tkolh

**Problem:** As per the given second link (with Tailwind css), the border not displayed surrounding the fieldset but the form fields and legend text displayed.

Simple code:

```
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Personalia:</legend>
      <label for="fname">First name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
      <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

**Requirement:** Requirement is that the fieldset needs to work exactly like the same in link 1 when we include tailwind css.. Don't know the reason why it doesn't work while we add tailwind css to the project. Kindly please help me to achieve the result.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the classes of the framework

```
<fieldset class="border border-solid border-gray-300 p-3">
    <legend class="text-sm">Specify products</legend>
    ...
</fieldset>
```

It will look something like this:
[image: fieldset]

Answer (score -1):

Tailwind CSS include reset css. If you don't use it, setup your config.

```js
  module.exports = {
    corePlugins: {
      preflight: false,
    }
  }
```

see document [Preflight - Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight)

Comment: I have added the configuartion in the file ```postcss.config.js``` but it doesn't work here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-vd49w

Comment: add in `tailwind.js`